# console.log(); not open message to the web console

Tags: jquery, html

I am new for programming and I had some issues. When I run `console.log();` chrome doesn't open message to the web console.

Here is a sample code that I wanted to be displayed in the web console.

```
console.log($("h1").css("color"));
```

When I refresh my web page this code should be displayed in the console as **rgb(255, 192, 203)** automatically but nothing happens. But if I open console manually I can get the answer immediately.

Any help on this, please?

Comment: You can use alert() For this specific purpose.

Comment: @kanishktanwar Firstly I think you've missed the point of the question, ie. the `console.log()` doesn't run. Secondly, ***never*** use `alert()` for debugging. It coerces everything to a string which can cause you to chase ghosts when trying to nail down a problem.

Comment: @Rory McCrossan thanks for point out.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your code run after rendering HTML.

For example:

```
h1 style="color: red">123</h1>
<script>
 console.log($("h1").css("color"));
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 style="color: red">123</h1>
<script>
 console.log("Run after rendering HTML: " + $("h1").css("color"));
</script>

<script>
 console.log("Run before rendering HTML: " + $("h2").css("color"));
</script>
<h2 style="color: red">123</h2>
```

Comment: I've just updated my answer with explanation more details, please take a look at @Pedram

Comment: @Phong I have used .js file as an external source. Let me show you my HTML code. 

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>my web</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>This is Simple Game</h1>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="game.js" charset="utf-8"></script>    

  </body>
</html>

**game.js** is the external file with console.log($("h1").css("color"));

Comment: You should make sure that your `game.js` file is loaded. You can add some code as I mentioned in my answer to check the result

Comment: @Phong Yes I have tested that by using **alert("this is my game");** and it perfectly works. I am looking everywhere how I can fix this but couldn't figure it out.